# Приложение не получает ответ с сервера

Tags: java, android, многопоточность

я передаю сообщение от сервера клиенту, но почему-то клиент не всегда получает это сообщение. С чем это может быть связано? Вот мой код отправки:

```
private void sendMessage(final byte[] message) {
    try {
        if (!tempClientSocket.isClosed()) {
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    PrintWriter out = null;
                    try {
                        DataOutputStream dOut = new DataOutputStream(tempClientSocket.getOutputStream());

                        dOut.write(message);           // write the message
                        dOut.flush();
                        if (!tempClientSocket.isClosed()){
                            if (message != null){
                                showMessage("TA send mess!", greenColor);
                            }
                            else{
                                showMessage("message null", Color.RED);
                            }
                            tempClientSocket.close();
                            showMessage("Ta Disconnected", greenColor);
                        }
                        else{
                            showMessage("socket close", Color.RED);
                        }
                        dOut.close();
                        //showMessage("TA send mess!", greenColor);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }).start();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: что значит не всегда? В каких случаях не получает? отправка при нажатии кнопки или у вас бесконечный цикл отправки?

Comment: @Dred, сообщения отправляются в ответ на запрос клиента. Я посмотрел логи и клиенту не всегда приходят сообщения, хотя когда доходят, разница между запросом и ответом, меньше секунды

Comment: На всякий случай, поставьте логироваться еще и ответ, посмотрите, всегда ли уходит и что уходит. Может у вас уходит null и вы, как бы, не видите, это сообщение на клиенте. Задайте явный ответ на каждое сообщение с добавлением префикса или постфикса, не важно. Чтобы вы точно различали то что пришло и то, что должно уйти.

Comment: @Dred, добавил код с изменениями, нуллов нет, соккет тоже не разрывается

Comment: А как у вас реализовано клиент-сервер? сервер на компьютере, клиент на телефоне? Делаете в рамках тестирования всё на 1 машине или скачиваете приложение на телефон и там делаете соединение с компьютером? Как именно теряются сообщения? Типа 1,2,3,4,....7,8,9 и т.д?

Comment: @Dred, К сожалению клиент запускать на одном устройстве не могу, так как его писал не я и исходников нет. Сообщения пропадают по такому принципу:
-Сообщение пришло на сервер
-Сервер ответил и отправил ответ клиенту
-Клиенту не пришло сообщения, он отправил запрос заново
-Сервер снова сделал все тоже самое
-Клиент получил ответ
Иногда клиент получает ответы правильно

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94198/discussion-between-dred-and--).